# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded If I want to send an array which has objects

Tags: javascript

I have a problem about use Javascript send Data(array) to laravel controller through ajax, but I met some problem.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

How can I solve this problem？

I made a class `Variable` which has some attributes and also some attributes like arr1,arr2 can save the other objects. My purpose is sending this `Variable` to PHP, and use PHP to upload this `Variable` to my database. My English is not very good.

```
class Variable {
    constructor() {
        this.name = null || 'reset';
        this.arr1 = [];
        this.arr2 = [];
    }
}

let vs = []
let v = new Variable();
vs.push(v)

$.ajax({
     url: 'laravel/xxxxController',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { objects: vs },
     success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
        })
    });
```

Comment: Usually `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.` means that you have an endless recursion.

Comment: Are you using loop somewhere in your code?? .Is  it the complete code?,coz this code looks ok.

Comment: I think I found some problem !!! Actually I use this.name to save dom element and the problem might be that , I guess is the dom element has some method have an endless recursion ???